# Object with uid key in Angularfire

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I'm a few days Firebase user and I tried to make function that creates an ordinary user(works), then add related to him node with his UID as a key in /users in database to store more info about user such as surname, address etc.

```
function _addUser(user) {
      var auth = $firebaseAuth();

      auth.$createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
        .then(function (firebaseUser) {
          _createUserNode(firebaseUser, user);
        });
    }
```

I assume that I'm doing something wrong with my ref.

```
function _createUserNode(firebaseUser, user) {
  var ref = firebase.database().ref(FirebaseUrl + "/users/" + firebaseUser.uid);
  var users = $firebaseArray(ref);

  users.$add(user).then(function () {
    //user added
  });
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AngularFire services `$firebaseArray` and `$firebaseObject` are useful to bind data from the Firebase Database to your AngularJS views. But if you're not binding them to the HTML, there is no need to use these services.

In your code, you're just trying to create a user node, which you can do with the regular Firebase JavaScript SDK:

```
function _createUserNode(firebaseUser, user) {
  var ref = firebase.database().ref(FirebaseUrl + "/users/" + firebaseUser.uid);
  ref.set(user).then(function () {
    //user added
  });
}
```

Since AngularFire is built on top of the Firebase JavaScript SDK, they interoperate nicely. Even if elsewhere you bind the user or list of users to the UI (with `$firebaseObject` or `$firebaseArray` respectively), those will show the change you make.

Comment: it's funny cuz I tested it pretty much this way too, but I give up with this error message:

`Firebase.child failed: First argument was an invalid path: "<my firebase url>/users/HJjb69auF6NJzpIcw2fgvNdXePZ2". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"`

Comment: As the error message says you have an invalid character in your `FirebaseUrl` variable. Most likely you're looking to do `firebase.database().ref("/users/" + firebaseUser.uid)`